# WIA versus WPD Digital Camera Image Acquisition and API

Tags: image, api, wia, wpd

We have a Windows Forms app running on XP that uses WIA to retrieve images from digital cameras attached to our company's field technician laptops. As clunky as the COM wrappers and APIs are, they've handled millions of images reliably. Looking now at inevitable migration to Win 7 and wondering if we should move from WIA to WPD (Windows Portable Devices) API.

Does anyone have experience migrating from WIA to WPD?  Or just working with WPD? Any pros or cons of staying WIA or going to WPD?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706594/will-a-vb6-app-using-wiaaut-dll-work-on-windows-vista-or-7