# Will a VB6 App Using wiaaut.dll work on Windows Vista or 7?

Tags: vb6, windows-vista, wia

I downloaded the Windows Image Acquisition Automation Layer sdk redistributable from Windows and the VB6 app I wrote to capture still images from a DSLR, wia-compliant camera works great on Windows XP.

Will the same app work on Windows Vista or 7? Microsoft says, "Windows Image Acquisition Automation Library v2.0 is only supported on Windows XP with Service Pack 1 installed.", but will the APIs work on newer OSs nonetheless? I really don't want to re-write the whole thing in C++ ...

Is there any other option available to me if I want to keep using VB6 but want to support newer OSs?

Comment: Duplicate of this older question - which unfortunately had no answers at all, so this question **shouldn't be closed**. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843381/wia-versus-wpd-digital-camera-image-acquisition-and-api

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you could use it but video support has been [removed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms630368(VS.85).aspx):

> WIA 1.0 was introduced in Windows Me and Windows XP and supports scanners, digital cameras and digital video equipment. WIA 2.0 was released with Windows Vista. WIA 2.0 is targeted towards scanners but continues to offer support for legacy WIA 1.0 applications and devices through a WIA 1.0 to WIA 2.0 compatibility layer provided by the WIA service. However, video content support was removed from WIA for Windows Vista. We recommend Windows Portable Devices (WPD) API for digital cameras and digital video equipment in the future. WIA 1.0 as well as STI TWAIN drivers are still supported directly on Windows Vista and Windows 7 alongside native WIA 2.0 device drivers and imaging applications.